# Disable div and only enable when radio button option is chosen

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How can I disable a div and activate it only after choosing a radio button option?

I can hide with hidden and show div when an option is selected, but hidden is not the desired property.

Does anyone know a possible solution?

```
<div class="col-s" [hidden]="show">

onValueChanged(c){
    if(c!=null){
      this.id= c.value.ID;
      this.show=false;
    }

  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by disable it? Usually 'disable' is used to refer to something that has an action related to it e.g. a button. You could use *ngIf="c", which will remove it and add it back completely from the DOM.

Comment: If `show` means what it says, you should change the code to: `[hidden]="!show"`.

Comment: I do not intend to hide, I intend to show everything, but prevent all clicks on this div until an option is chosen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `pointer-events: none` to prevent clicking.

component html

```html
<div class="col-s" [ngStyle]="{'pointer-events': !show ? 'none' : 'initial' }">
  this button is only clickable if you choose -> show
  <button>click</button>
</div>

<label for="showtrue">show</label>
<input id="showtrue" type="radio" name="show" [value]="true" [(ngModel)]="show">

<br />

<label for="showfalse">dont't show (not clickable)</label>
<input id="showfalse" type="radio" name="show" [value]="false" [(ngModel)]="show">
```

component ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  // if you want initial false, change it here
  show = true; // initial true (div is clickable)
}
```

if `show` is true, you can click. If it is false, you can't.

---

edit: here is an example how it works: 
https://ng-run.com/edit/Kzn3ChvHWUD4Jxn1cc2r

Comment: Do I need to just put this or do I still have to do if? I was in doubt :(

Comment: you only have to set the boolean value for **show** with your radio buttons